# Conditions for the solution to a matrix differential equation (with exponentials) to be a valid probability distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-distributions, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

Define $F(z) : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]^2$, $C \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ and $D \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$.  The scalar $z \in [0, \infty)$

A few further assumptions:

- $C$ is negative definite and diagonalizable, but not symmetric
- $\min(eig(-C)) > 1$, but that is likely overkill here.
- $D > 0$
- $F(z)$ has full support on $[0,\infty)$
- If it is useful, the sum of $-C^{-1} D$ is 1

**Short Version of the Question:**

Define the PDF using the matrix exponential.
$$F'(z) = e^{C z} D$$

The question is: under what additional conditions on $C$ and $D$ is this a valid PDF?  In particular,

1. $\lim_{z\to\infty}F'(z) = 0$
2. $F'(z) > 0$ for all $z$.

I believe the 1st condition only requires a negative definite $C$.  But see an example at the bottom of this question shows that this is not enough for the 2nd condition

**An approach?**

As the limit must go to $0$ and it must be positive, is it sufficient to prove monotonicity of $F'(z)$?  This is certainly true with any reasonable solutions to the problem.  If so, can we simply prove for all $z \geq 0$ that
$$
F''(z) < 0
$$
From the definition, doesn't this mean proving for all $z$ that the following has no solution for $z\geq 0$?
$$
e^{C z} C D = 0
$$
If we do the diagonalization, $C \equiv Q B Q^{-1}$ then this becomes,
$$
Q e^{B z} Q^{-1} C D = 0
$$
But I couldn't figure out anything more after this...(This could be related to [Can matrix exponentials ever be negative? If so, under what conditions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926943/can-matrix-exponentials-ever-be-negative-if-so-under-what-conditions))

**Background:** I have a two-state Markov chain and a continuous state, and have a Kolmogorov forward equation to describe the stationary CDF.   then the ODE can be written as:
$$F'(z) = C F(z) + D$$
Where $z \in [0,\infty)$ and initial condition $F(0) = 0$ (and $C$ and $D$ will fulfill some conservation of mass $F_1(\infty) + F_2(\infty) = 1$)

The solution to this ODE for the CDF is:
$$
F(z) = (e^{C z} - \mathbb{I})C^{-1}D
$$
With the PDF:
$$
F'(z) = e^{C z} D
$$

From this, you can see why  $\sum -C^{-1} D = 1$ to ensure that $\sum \lim_{z\to\infty} F(z) = 1$

**Example (one I want to reject)**
Writing in Matlab to simplify the copy/paste, define the following example

```
C = [- 2.2959 -1.5; -.1 -1.6918];
min(eig(-C)) %Can check the eigenvalues to ensure negative definite
D = [2.0; 0.6918];
F_p = @(z) expm(C * z) * D;

%Evaluate at a few z's
F_p(1) %Both > 0
F_p(3) %One of them < 0!!!
F_p(100) %They both converge to 0

%Could diagonalize C
[Q,B] = eig(C)
% Then define F''(z)
F_pp = @(z) Q * diag(exp(diag(B) * z))* inv(Q) * C * D
```

Comment: I am missing something. If $F$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $[0,1]$ how can it be a probability distribution function?

Comment: There is a binary discrete state as well as the continuous one in z.  So choosing choosing one of them, say $F_1(z)$, gives a (unnormalized) CDF conditioning on the first binary state (I say unnormalized because I am not dividing by $1 - F_1(\infty)$)

Comment: I changed the $\mathbb{R}^2$, which was correct, to $[0,1]^2$ which is a tighter range and perhaps makes that this is a CDF clearer.