# When is there a vector $D$ with positive coordinates such that $e^{Ct}D$ has a negative coordinate?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

Let $C$ be a $2 \times 2$ asymmetric matrix with real entries. Assume that $C$ has strictly negative, real eigenvalues. Fix $D\in\mathbb{R}^2$, where $D > 0$ (i.e., both coordinates are strictly positive). Let $t \geq 0$ be a scalar and define the vector valued function using the matrix exponential,
$$
H(t) = e^{C t} D\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$
Denote $\min(H(t))<0$ if at least one of the elements is less than $0$.

> Fixing $D > 0$, under what conditions on $C$ and $D$ does a $t^{*}> 0$ exist such that $\min(H(t^*)) < 0$?  Or conversely, given a numerical $C$ and $D$, how can I test whether the $H(t) > 0$ for all $t$?

Ideal conditions are checking signs of eigenvectors or diagonal elements of $C$, etc.  If they can be done without a particular $D$ matrix, so much the better.

A few notes:

- If possible, you can use the assumption that $-C^{-1} D \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 &1\end{bmatrix} = 1$.  i.e. the sum of $-C^{-1}D = 1$  This comes out of necessary equilibrium condition to ensure that $H(t)$ is a valid PDF, and may pin down requirements to make the answer only requirements on $C$.
- $C$ negative definite should be enough to ensure that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}H(t) = 0$
- If you wish, assume that C is diagonalizable and denote $C \equiv Q S Q^{-1}$, where $S$ the matrix of eigenvalues (both $< 0$).  In that case, 
  $$
  H(t)= Q e^{S t} Q^{-1} D
  $$

**Solution Approach?:** Clearly, having negative eigenvalues of $C$ ensures convergence of $H(t) \to 0$, but what do the eigenvectors of $C$ tell us? Can they tell us from which direction it approaches $0$ (given the sign of $D$)?

I notice that in examples which break, one of the eigenvectors has the same signs for both coordinates, while the other has different signs?  Could $Q \leq 0$ be the answer?

**Example where it goes below 0 with negative definite C:**
See the following matlab code:

```
C = [- 2.2959 -1.5; -.1 -1.6918];
min(eig(-C)) %Can check the eigenvalues to ensure negative definite
D = [2.0; 0.6918];
F_p = @(z) expm(C * z) * D;
%Evaluate at a few z's
F_p(1) %Both > 0
F_p(3) %One of them < 0!!!
F_p(100) %They both converge to 0
%Could diagonalize C
[Q,B] = eig(C)
% Then define F''(z)
F_pp = @(z) Q * diag(exp(diag(B) * z))* inv(Q) * C * D
```

**Added from Idea Given in Solution:**
The following may be a sketch of a proof that $D$ as the eigenvector of $C$ fulfills the requirement, Preliminaries:

1. $A$ and $A^{n}$ have the same eigenvectors and if $\lambda $ is a root
   of $A,\ \lambda ^{n\text{ }}\ $is a root of $A^{n}.\ $And $-A$ has roots $
   -\lambda $
2. $If$ $A$ is non-negative (with some positive elements) it has a
   non-negative eigenvector $v\geq 0$ associated to a dominant root $\hat{
   \lambda}>0,$  which is real, simple and larger in modulus than its other
   roots.
3. $A$ and $-A\ $\ have the same eigenvectors.

Now consider $e^{C t}D=\left[ I+C t+\frac{1}{2!}\left( C t\right) ^{2}+\frac{1}{
3!}\left( C t\right) ^{3}+\frac{1}{4!}\left( C t\right) ^{4}+\frac{1}{5!}
\left( C t\right) ^{5}+\frac{1}{6!}\left( C t\right) ^{6}+..\right] D$ where $
C\leq 0.$ Take $v$ to be the dominant eigenvector of $-C.$ So if $\lambda $
is the dominant root of $-C,$ then the minimum eigenvalue of $-C$ is $
-\lambda .$ Take $D=v.$ Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
C t v &=&\left( -\lambda t\right) v \\
\left( C t\right) ^{2}v &=&\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{2}v \\
\left( C t\right) ^{3}v &=&\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{3}v
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{C t}v &=&\left[ I+C t+\frac{1}{2!}\left( C t\right) ^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\left(
C t\right) ^{3}+\frac{1}{4!}\left( C t\right) ^{4}+\frac{1}{5!}\left(
C t\right) ^{5}+\frac{1}{6!}\left( C t\right) ^{6}+..\right] v \\
&=&\left[ 1+\left( -\lambda t\right) +\frac{1}{2!}\left( -\lambda t\right)
^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{3}+\frac{1}{4!}\left( -\lambda
t\right) ^{4}+\frac{1}{5!}\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{5}+\frac{1}{6!}\left(
-\lambda t\right) ^{6}+..\right] v
\end{eqnarray*}
But by definition

$$
e^{-\lambda t}=\left[ 1+\left( -\lambda t\right) +\frac{1}{2!}\left(
-\lambda t\right) ^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{3}+\frac{1}{4!}
\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{4}+\frac{1}{5!}\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{5}+
\frac{1}{6!}\left( -\lambda t\right) ^{6}+..\right] 
$$
So
$$
e^{C t}v=\left[ I+C t+\frac{1}{2!}\left( C t\right) ^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\left(
C t\right) ^{3}+\frac{1}{4!}\left( C t\right) ^{4}+\frac{1}{5!}\left(
C t\right) ^{5}+\frac{1}{6!}\left( C t\right) ^{6}+..\right] v=e^{-\lambda
t}v\geq 0
$$
since $v$ is the non-negative eigenvector. Choose $D=H\left(
0\right) =v$ and $H\left( t\right) =e^{Ct}D\geq 0.$

Comment: It's hard to tell what kinds of conditions you are looking for. On fixed $C$ for all $D>0$, on fixed $D>0$ for all negative definite $C$, an estimate on $t^*$ for fixed $C$ and fixed $D$? What exactly would you like to establish by taking limits? I wasn't sure what to focus on.

Comment: I tried to make this a little more clear.  I don't really care about a particular $t^*$, just whether one exists or not.  What I want to be able to do is check for a given $C$, and $D$ whether $H(t) > 0$, which is what I want, by checking some conditions on the matrix and vectors $C$ and $D$.

Comment: I found a flaw in my original argument, and amended the answer accordingly. It still works if $C$ is symmetric negative definite, but not if it is only diagonalizable with negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Alas, our $C$ are never symmetric (but is strictly negative, diaogonalization, negative eigenvalues of modulus > 1).  Did you take a look at the proof sketched above, which doesn't seem to require symmetry, but is fairly loose.  Is there another requirement that will make the assymetric versions have a unique $D$ (to a scale) as before?

Comment: Oh, one thing I have noticed in our example:  if we add in a condition that second eigenvector has coordinates of different signs, then we go back to the uniqueness.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, coordinates of opposite signs in the second eigenvector are necessary and sufficient for uniqueness. Symmetric is sufficient but it is far from necessary. You can pick two arbitrary linearly independent vectors, and make them the eigenvectors of some matrix with the eigenvalues also of your choice.

Comment: Great, then I think that is a complete set of requirements. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $D>0$ then the necessary and sufficient condition for $e^{C t}D$ to have a negative coordinate is for $e^{Ct}$ to have a negative entry. This is because when the row where the negative entry is gets multiplied by $D$ we can make the corresponding coordinate of $D$ so large and the rest so small that the result is negative. For $e^{Ct}$ to have non-negative entries for all $t\geq0$ it is necessary and sufficient that $C$ be non-negative off of the diagonal as I explained in my [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926943/can-matrix-exponentials-ever-be-negative-if-so-under-what-conditions/927087#927087). So if $C$ has a negative entry off of the diagonal $e^{Ct}$ will have a negative entry in it, and so will $e^{Ct}D$ for some $D>0$. In fact, $e^{Ct}$ starts having negative entries right away in this case, for any $t>0$, because $e^{Ct}\approx I+tC$ for small $t$, and the negative entry from $C$ is inherited by $e^{Ct}$. For a particular $D>0$ the critical time $t^*$ after which $e^{Ct}D$ first has a negative coordinate will depend on $D$ of course.

You may be interested in the [general theory of positive and non-negative matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices) in this sense that goes back to Perron and Frobenius. In particular, the theorem of Perron-Frobenius implies that positive matrices have an eigenvector with positive coordinates corresponding to the eigenvalue with the largest absolute value. If $C$ is non-negative off diagonal then $e^{Ct}$ is non-negative and they share eigenvectors, so $C$ also has an eigenvector with positive coordinates corresponding to the eigenvalue with the largest real part. This explains why one of the eigenvectors has the same signs. If $C$ is also symmetric then the other eigenvector has to be orthogonal to it, hence have the opposite signs.

We can now say something for $C$ negative off of the diagonal. Then $-C$ has the same eigenvectors as $C$, but is positive off of the diagonal, so by the Perron-Frobenius theorem both have an eigenvector $u$ with positive coordinates. It's exactly the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $C$ with the smallest real part. Since $e^{C t}u=e^{\lambda t}u$ when $D=u$ the entries of $e^{C t}D$ remain positive for all $t$.

However, if $C$ is symmetric negative definite then this property is unstable. The other eigenvector $v$ is then orthogonal to $u$, and so has both positive and negative coordinates. Moreover, its eigenvalue $\mu$ is bigger, i.e. less negative than $\lambda$. So if $D=\alpha u+\beta v$ in the eigenbasis then $e^{C t}D=\alpha e^{\lambda t}u+\beta e^{\mu t}v$, and the second term dominates for large $t$. Regardless of the sign of $\beta$ the vector $\beta e^{\mu t}v$, and therefore $e^{C t}D$ for large $t$, will have a negative coordinate. In other words, as long as $D$ is not proportional to the positive eigenvector, $e^{C t}D$ will have a negative coordinate eventually, and the limit of $\min H(t)$ will be approached from the negative side.

On the other hand, if we only know that $C$ is diagonalizable with negative eigenvalues then the second eigenvector $v$ may also have positive coordinates, and then so will any positive linear combinations of $u$ and $v$. Therefore, $e^{C t}D=\alpha e^{\lambda t}u+\beta e^{\mu t}v$ remains positive for all $t\geq0$ if $\alpha,\beta>0$, and this property is stable, e.g. if say $D=u+v$ then all its small enough perturbations have the same property.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help on both questions.  I posted this new one because I was worried I had asked the wrong question last time, but it sounds like I may have asked a correct one.  A few answers: 1) No symmetry required. 2) require real, strictly negative eigenvalues.

Comment: From this, it sounds like the answer to my question may simply be that: For any $D > 0$, if both off-diagonal terms are positive, then $H(t) > 0$ for all $t$ (and $\lim_{t\to\infty}H(t) = 0$ due to the negative real eigenvalues)?

Comment: Actually, the more I look at my model, it is clear that the entire $C$ matrix is always negative.  Dose this mean that $H(t) < 0$ for some $t$ for any $D$, or could there be a $D$ where $H(t) > 0$ for all $t$?

Comment: If both off-diagonal terms are positive and both eigenvalues are negative, then for any $D>0$ it's true that $H(t)>0$ for all $t\geq0$, and $\lim_{t\to\infty}H(t)=0$. By "always negative" do you mean all four entries are negative?

Comment: Yes, all 4 are negative. Does this work in converse where all 4 negative means there does not exist a D such that H(t) >0 for all t? I hope not...

Comment: Taking a large $t$ limit, I am curious if given the eigenvalues $\alpha, \beta < 0$, the decomposition from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Evaluation_by_Laurent_series of $e^{A t} = s_0(t) I + s_1(t) A$ with $s_0(t) = \frac{\alpha e^{\beta t} - \beta e^{\alpha t}}{\alpha - \beta}$ and $s_1(t) = \frac{e^{\alpha t} - e^{\beta t}}{\alpha - \beta}$ could help

Comment: See the added two paragraphs. There is a vector for which $H(t)$ stays positive, but only one up to scale. For any other vector $H(t)$ eventually becomes negative and stays there all the way to the limit.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, I think this completely answers my question, but let me think a little on it tonight.  I checked and one can find the numerical scaling to ensure that sum$(-C^{-1} D)$ equal $1$ as I stated above, which would mean that there is a single $D$ for any negative $C$ which can be a valid PDF for my model (and fulfill the integrability constraint).

Comment: This has certainly earned the bounty.  A coauthor followed what you had written, and wrote up the above proof for part of the direction.  We still had a question:  If $C < 0$, irreducible, then doesn't this mean that the inequality is strict, $H(t) = e^{-\lambda t} v > 0$.  If so, does this mean that there should be perturbations in a neighborhood of $v > 0$ that also solve this with strict inequality?  We weren't sure.  This proof, if correct, doesn't address the other direction of non-eigenvector $\implies$ negative.

Comment: The inequality is strict in the irreducible case, but perturbation argument only works for a fixed $t$. For larger and larger $t$ the perturbation will have to be smaller and smaller to keep $H(t)$ positive, so none works for all $t$. If $v$ (which I called $u$ in the answer) is perturbed in a way that introduces a non-zero component along the other eigenvector, no matter how small, that component comes to dominate $H(t)$ eventually, and a negative coordinate will appear. The smaller the perturbation the longer it will take, but it will happen.