# Requirement on $C$ such that $e^{C t} \cdot \left[ \begin{matrix} d & 0\end{matrix}\right]$ is negative for some $t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

Let $C$ be a $2 \times 2$, *negative definite* asymmetric matrix with real entries. The matrix $C$ has negative coefficients, except for a single positive one in a corner.  Furthermore, assume that $d > 0$.

Define:
$$
H(t) = e^{C t}\cdot \left[\begin{matrix}d \\ 0\end{matrix}\right]\in\mathbb{R}^2
$$
Denote $\min(H(t))<0$ if at least one of the elements is less than $0$.

> Fixing $d > 0$, under what conditions (beyond negative definiteness) on $C$ and $d$ does a $t^{*}> 0$ exist such that $\min(H(t^*)) < 0$?

Note: As I need to prove that a negative $H(t)$ always exists in my setup, I would be perfectly happy if you were also able to show that this is not possible given the assumptions.

(this is related to [When is there a vector $D$ with positive coordinates such that $e^{Ct}D$ has a negative coordinate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929113/when-is-there-a-vector-d-with-positive-coordinates-such-that-ectd-has-a-n) but with different assumptions, as we no longer use Perron and Frobenius since the matrix is not purely negative).

Comment: What do you mean by negative definite in this context?

Comment: Trace(C) < 0 && Det(C) < 0 was my test.  SHoudl I put that in directly instead?

Comment: Really, $\det(C) < 0$?  For a symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix, that would mean the matrix is **indefinite**.

Comment: The matrix is asymmetric.  All entries are 0 except a single positive corner

Comment: err, less than 0 except a single positive corner

Comment: @RobertIsrael Noticed your affiliation.  Greetings from the UBC economics department, and thanks for looking at my post.